# when i try to run the project with library @google/model-viewer by npm start i get this error

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@google/model-viewer": "^1.11.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0"
  }
}
```

`PS C:\Users\AA\Desktop\3Dpro\my-app> npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AA\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-04-05T20_22_54_567Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\AA\Desktop\3Dpro\my-app>

I am using a library for 3D ( @google/model-viewer)

this is my code:
import '@google/model-viewer'
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class PersonalDesign extends Component {
render() {
return (


)
}
}

Comment: The `start` script appears to be missing from your `package.json` file. Maybe check you've a `"start": "react-scripts start",` or similar entry in the scripts. Can you include your `package.json` file in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `package.json` file is missing the scripts for some reason. Add them back in. You also appear to be missing the `react-dom` and `react-scripts` dependencies.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@google/model-viewer": "^1.11.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

After updating/saving your package.json file, run `npm i` to install the dependencies and then run `npm start` to start your project.

Comment: i tried to add the scripts and now i have this error: > my-app@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
PS C:\Users\AA\Desktop\3Dpro\my-app>

Comment: first of all thanks for the help but it did not help me . and it was a project to try the library (model viewer) but i have a bigger project wuth errors can i share and look at it?

Comment: yes of course i will share evrething ,But in a new question that can not add everything in the comment here.

Comment: @סחראבוריש Oh, sorry, I thought it was assumed/implied the new details would go up in your post as an edit. If you ask a new question feel free to ping me here with a link to it and I can take a look.

Comment: this is the link to the question with all details :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71787006/i-have-a-problem-running-code-with-npm-start-ts2339-property-model-viewer-d

Comment: You can look at it ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @סחראבוריש Oh, totally sorry... I had copied some of your code into a sandbox and tried some quick edits to see if I could resolve the typescript error.... then I forgot to leave a comment. I'll take another look.